# Замена строк в файле при их добавлении

Tags: python

В функцию поочередно поступает переменная, и вместо того что бы строки добавлялись в файл, они заменяются

```
def writer(file, ips, e = "default"):
    try:
        if e == "default":
             file.write(ips+"\n")
        if e == "notdefault"
             file.write(ips + " - p\n")
    except:
        print("Some problems with writing to file")
    finally:
        file.close()
```

Comment: что вы думаете происходит, если попытаться записать что-то в закрытый файл? Что вы думаете file.close() делает?

Comment: @jfs, на самом деле не знаю. Во всех книгах читал что так нужно делать. Проблема заключается в file.close()?

Comment: если не можете узнать, что file.close метод делает, то нужно это в первую очередь сделать (чтобы на подобных простейших вопросах не застревать): найти  способ читать документацию (учите хотя бы подмножество английского, чтобы проблем с популярным API не возникало (слова типа open, close), найдите готовый перевод, на лету машинный перевод используйте, итд)

Comment: Делать нужно, но в другом месте.

Comment: @Эникейщик, кажется понял где, пойду пробовать.

Comment: @jfs  Окей, спасибо!